# How to make an html element always stay inside boundaries?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm coding a search algorithms visualizer in react and I'm having a small glitch whenever I move my `start` or `end` nodes. When I press down on the mouse and move the cursor over the board, the nodes update accordingly. That is until the cursor goes beyond the boundaries of the grid, leaving a node with the `start-node` or `end-node` classname, visually creating two (or more) nodes, as such:

[image]

This doesn't affect functionality but it is pretty annoying. Ideally, I'm looking to make it work like it does on this demo: https://pathfindout.com/, where it doesn't matter where the user moves the cursor while dragging the nodes, they always stay inside the limits of the board. This is the code for my `Node` component so far:

```
const Node = ({ row, col, isWall, isStart, isEnd, handleState, handleMouseState }) => {

    const { nodesMatrix, updateNodes } = handleState;
    const { isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown } = handleMouseState;

    //This variable helps to prevent the user
    //from stacking the 'start' and 'end' nodes
    //on top of each other. Instead they jump to
    //the next available sibling.
    let prevCollision = null;


    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        isStart ? setIsMouseDown(1) : isEnd ? setIsMouseDown(2) : setIsMouseDown(3);
    };

    const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
        setIsMouseDown(0);
        const newParent = e.target.id ? e.target : null;
        const [newParentRow, newParentCol] = newParent.id.match(/\d+/g);

        if (isMouseDown === 1) updateNodes(false, true, parseInt(newParentRow), parseInt(newParentCol));

        if (isMouseDown === 2) updateNodes(false, false, parseInt(newParentRow), parseInt(newParentCol));

        if (isMouseDown === 3) updateNodes(true, false, parseInt(newParentRow), parseInt(newParentCol));
    };


    const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
        const newParent = e.target.id ? e.target : null;
        const prevParent = e.relatedTarget;
        const [newParentRow, newParentCol] = e.target.id.match(/\d+/g);
        const nodePointer = nodesMatrix[newParentRow][newParentCol];


        //moving start node
        if (isMouseDown === 1) {
            const collision = isEnd;
            if (!collision) {
                prevParent.classList.remove('start-node');
                newParent.classList.add('start-node');
                nodePointer.isStart = true;
            } else {
                prevCollision = prevParent;
            }
        };

        //moving end node
        if (isMouseDown === 2) {
            const collision = isStart;
            if (!collision) {
                prevParent.classList.remove('end-node');
                newParent.classList.add('end-node');
                nodePointer.isEnd = true;
            } else {
                prevCollision = prevParent;
            }
        }

        //creating walls
        if (isMouseDown === 3) {
            if(!isStart && !isEnd) {
                if (isWall) {
                    newParent.classList.remove('wall-node');
                    nodePointer.isWall = false;
                } else {
                    newParent.classList.add('wall-node');
                    nodePointer.isWall = true;
                };
            }      
        };
    };


    const handleMouseLeave = (e) => {
        const prevParent = e.target.id ? e.target : null;
        const [prevRow, prevCol] = prevParent.id.match(/\d+/g);
        const nodePointer = nodesMatrix[prevRow][prevCol];

        if (isMouseDown === 1) {
            if (prevCollision) prevCollision.classList.remove('start-node');
            nodePointer.isStart = false;
        };

        if (isMouseDown === 2) {
            if (prevCollision) prevCollision.classList.remove('end-node');
            nodePointer.isEnd = false;
        };
    };

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const target = e.target.id ? e.target : null;
        const [row, col] = target.id.match(/\d+/g);
        const nodePointer = nodesMatrix[row][col];

        if (isWall) {
            target.classList.remove('wall-node');
            nodePointer.isWall = false;
        } else {
            target.classList.add('wall-node');
            nodePointer.isWall = true;
        }
    };


    return (
        <div id={`node-${ row }-${ col }`}
            onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
            onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            onClick={(isStart || isEnd) ? null : handleClick}
            className={
                `${ isStart ? 'start-node' : isEnd ? 'end-node' : isWall ? 'wall-node' : '' }
         node w-6 h-6 border border-blue-400`} />
    )
};

export default Node
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is the parent `Grid` component if it helps with anything:

```
const Grid = () => {

    const [nodesMatrix, setNodesMatrix] = useState([]);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(5);

    const [startNodeRow, setStartNodeRow] = useState(6);
    const [startNodeCol, setStartNodeCol] = useState(10);
    const [endNodeRow, setEndNodeRow] = useState(6);
    const [endNodeCol, setEndNodeCol] = useState(17);

    // 1 to move 'start' node;
    // 2 to move 'end' node;
    // 3 to create a wall;
    const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(0);
    

    //Initializes Grid
    useEffect(() => {
        const cells = [];
        const startNodeRow = 6;
        const startNodeCol = 10;
        const endNodeRow = 6;
        const endNodeCol = 17;

            for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                const currentRow = [];
                for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                    const node = {
                        row,
                        col,
                        isWall: false,
                        isStart: row === startNodeRow && col === startNodeCol,
                        isEnd: row === endNodeRow && col === endNodeCol,
                        distance: Infinity,
                        visited: false,
                        previousNode: null
                    };
                    currentRow.push(node);
                };
                cells.push(currentRow);
            };
            
        setNodesMatrix(cells);
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        clearAllNodesStyles();
    }, [isMouseDown]);

    const resetMatrix = (matrix) => {
        const matrixRef = [...matrix]

            for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                    const node = matrixRef[row][col];
                    node.distance = Infinity;
                    node.previousNode = null;
                    node.visited = false;
                    node.isWall = node.isStart || node.isEnd ? false : node.isWall
                };
            };

        return matrixRef
    };

    const updateNodes = (isWall, isStart, newRow, newCol)  => {
            const newGrid = resetMatrix(nodesMatrix);

            if(isWall) return setNodesMatrix(newGrid);

            if (isStart) {
                setStartNodeRow(newRow);
                setStartNodeCol(newCol);
            } else {
                  setEndNodeRow(newRow);
                  setEndNodeCol(newCol);  
            };

            setNodesMatrix(newGrid);
    };


    return (
            <div className="flex flex-col self-center">
                {nodesMatrix.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={rowIndex} className='flex'>
                            {row.map((node, index) => {

                                const { row, col, isWall, isStart, isEnd } = node;

                                return <Node
                                    key={index}
                                    row={row}
                                    col={col}
                                    isWall={isWall}
                                    isStart={isStart}
                                    isEnd={isEnd}
                                    handleState={{nodesMatrix, updateNodes}}
                                    handleMouseState={{isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown}} />
                            })}
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                }

                <button
                    onClick={() => visualizeDijkstra(nodesMatrix, { startNodeRow, startNodeCol, endNodeRow, endNodeCol, speed })}
                    className="...">
                    Search Path
                </button>
            </div>
    )

};

export default Grid
```

Comment: In `handleMouseUp`, why are you setting `setIsMouseDown(0)` and later checking if `isMouseDown` equals to 1/2/3? Shouldn't you set the state after checking those conditions?

Comment: @miniature It doesn't make any difference, the state passed down to the function is the one previous to the state update

Comment: if possible, please provide the parent component code too.

Comment: @miniature Sure!

Comment: The problem is, you are not tracking whether the mouse going out of the `Grid` or not. You r also not storing the last `Node` before going out of grid. As a result, when the mouse again enter the Grid, the program doesn't know which one is the last node which it visited. So, it can't remove the class from the last node.

Comment: Hey @LeoM, is it solved?

Comment: @miniature Yeah, kind of. It isn't the exact behavior I'm looking for but implementing that would take more time than I'm willing to spend on a side project, besides this solves the massive headache this was. Thanks for your help and checking in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, The problem is, you are not tracking whether the mouse going out of the Grid or not. You are also not storing the last Node before going out of grid. As a result, when the mouse again enters the Grid, the program doesn't know which one is the last node which it visited. So, it can't remove the class from the last node.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { clearAllNodesStyles, visualizeDijkstra } from "../algorithms/dijkstra";
import Node from "./Node";

const COLUMNS = 60;
const ROWS = 25;

const Grid = () => {
    const [nodesMatrix, setNodesMatrix] = useState([]);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(5);

    const [startNodeRow, setStartNodeRow] = useState(6);
    const [startNodeCol, setStartNodeCol] = useState(10);
    const [endNodeRow, setEndNodeRow] = useState(6);
    const [endNodeCol, setEndNodeCol] = useState(17);

    // 1 to move 'start' node;
    // 2 to move 'end' node;
    // 3 to create a wall;
    const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(0);

    //Initializes Grid
    useEffect(() => {
        const cells = [];
        const startNodeRow = 6;
        const startNodeCol = 10;
        const endNodeRow = 6;
        const endNodeCol = 17;

        for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            const currentRow = [];
            for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                const node = {
                    row,
                    col,
                    isWall: false,
                    isStart: row === startNodeRow && col === startNodeCol,
                    isEnd: row === endNodeRow && col === endNodeCol,
                    distance: Infinity,
                    visited: false,
                    previousNode: null,
                };
                currentRow.push(node);
            }
            cells.push(currentRow);
        }

        setNodesMatrix(cells);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        clearAllNodesStyles();
    }, [isMouseDown]);

    const resetMatrix = (matrix) => {
        const copyCat = [...matrix];

        for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                const node = copyCat[row][col];
                const newNode = {
                    ...node,
                    distance: Infinity,
                    previousNode: null,
                    visited: false,
                    isWall: node.isStart || node.isEnd ? false : node.isWall,
                };

                copyCat[row][col] = newNode;
            }
        }

        return copyCat;
    };

    const updateNodes = (isWall, isStart, newRow, newCol) => {
        const newGrid = resetMatrix(nodesMatrix);

        if (isWall) return setNodesMatrix(newGrid);

        if (isStart) {
            setStartNodeRow(newRow);
            setStartNodeCol(newCol);
        } else {
            setEndNodeRow(newRow);
            setEndNodeCol(newCol);
        }

        setNodesMatrix(newGrid);
    };

    const handleTouchBoundaryLine = (e) => {
        const prevParent = e.target.id ? e.target : null;
        if (isMouseDown === 1 || isMouseDown === 2) {
            if (prevParent) {
                const [prevRow, prevCol] = prevParent.id.match(/\d+/g);
                const nodePointer = nodesMatrix[prevRow][prevCol];

                if (isMouseDown === 1) nodePointer.isStart = true;

                if (isMouseDown === 2) nodePointer.isEnd = true;

                let clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                clickEvent.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
                prevParent.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col self-center">
            <div id="grid-boundary" onMouseLeave={handleTouchBoundaryLine}>
                {nodesMatrix.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={rowIndex} className="flex">
                            {row.map((node, index) => {
                                const { row, col, isWall, isStart, isEnd } = node;

                                return (
                                    <Node
                                        key={index}
                                        row={row}
                                        col={col}
                                        isWall={isWall}
                                        isStart={isStart}
                                        isEnd={isEnd}
                                        handleState={{ nodesMatrix, updateNodes }}
                                        handleMouseState={{ isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown }}
                                    />
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>

            <button
                onClick={() =>
                    visualizeDijkstra(nodesMatrix, {
                        startNodeRow,
                        startNodeCol,
                        endNodeRow,
                        endNodeCol,
                        speed,
                    })
                }
                className="h-20 w-full text-white hover:bg-blue-800 bg-blue-700 place-self-end"
            >
                Search Path
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Grid;
```

I have added a boundary line/div around the grid. So, whenever the mouse leaves that div, it will dispatch mouseup event on the previous visited Node and mark it as the start/end Node.